# What CSS rules does AMP HTML support?

Tags: css, amp-html

I have read https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/docs/create_page.md about the usage of CSS, but am not sure what CSS selectors the format allows. Are there any restrictions on selectors/properties?

Can style declarations be placed anywhere in `<html>` or only in `<head>`?

Is it possible to include any external stylesheets?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[**From the Official AMP GitHub Documentation:**](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md#stylesheets)

- You may include **1** `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of the DOM. You must append `amp-custom` to the `<style>` tag like this: `<style amp-custom>your style rules here</style>`
- You may not alter the `margin` property on the `body` element.
- You may not load an external stylesheet or import one via `@import`
- You may not add style attributes to elements.
- You may not use the `!important` qualifier.
- You may never use any of the following properties:

  - `behavior:`
  - `overflow: scroll`
  - `overflow: auto`
  - `transition:`
  - `filter`
  - `animation`
  - `-moz-binding`
- You may use the following selectors:

  - `.class` e.g. `.row`
  - `#id` e.g. `#sidebar`
  - `tag-name` e.g. `section`
  - selector, selector e.g. `.row, .clearfix` or `#sidebar, #main-body, article`
  - media queries e.g. `@media (max-width:48em){}`
- You may use the following pseudo-selectors:

  - `:hover`
  - `:active`
  - `:visited`
- You may not use any `input` elements with the exception of `button` (as these are used to interact with AMP Web Components).
- You are obliged to avoid using class names prefixed with `-amp` or `-amp-` to avoid conflicting with AMP components. You can override the styles of these components if you wish.
- Your style rules must not exceed 50KB.
- You may acquire font assets either through a whitelisted font vendor (... Google Fonts) or by fetching the font through @font-face via HTTP/HTTPS — i.e. not via `data:` or JavaScript plugin (since JS is banned).

---

Comment: You may also not declare the `type` attribute on `button` elements. Just a heads up.

Comment: This is anecdotal, because the AMP validator is a piece of crap, but after spending some time doing away with some invalid selectors, I can confirm that `:first-child`,`:last-child`,`:before`,`:after` pseudo-elements, and direct descendent (`>`) selectors all pass validation.

Comment: Thanks Cesar; however, I must warn you that I've not kept my answer up to date with the spec over time, so my answer may not be 100% accurate any more. I'd cross-reference with [the most up to date info](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec.html) ([also viewable here on github](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md#stylesheets))

Comment: It pretty much is, made a dummy page with your specs and worked great. Got me on the right path. Problem I face now knowing how AMP works is do I want to revamp my entire site off bootstrap:(

Comment: If you do decide to move away from Bootstrap, perhaps an alternative would be useful. [Min.css](http://mincss.com) or something like it would fit within the max size for the amp-custom stylesheet, avoid violating rules, and give a Bootstrappy look and feel — with a little embellishment.

Comment: I'm assuming this is all CSS and no JS

Comment: It is indeed, though I've not tried it because I tend to roll my own CSS with each project I do. 

[Sometimes CSS can be enough though.](https://dev.amdouglas.com/amphtml-examples/nojs-carousel/#div1)

Comment: Yeah I can live without the JS just need to restructure those pages that have it. No more jstables:(

Comment: Any alternatives to JS tables with CSS?

Comment: Are you thinking about AMPing [the site in your profile](https://www.wordgamedictionary.com)? You could use some really, *really* hacky CSS to achieve a similar effect as pagination on tables, but honestly I wouldn't recommend it. 

Best bet would be to create components and load them with amp-iframe custom elements. It can be done: as an experiment, I built a fully functional web forum which passed AMP validation, by loading CRUD forms in amp-iframes.

Comment: yeah thats the site, I am going to try the amp-iframe thing

Comment: @amdouglas. Could you check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199925/external-style-sheet-is-not-working-in-amp-pages. I stuck in AMP.

Answer (score 0):

"transition" css property is not disallowed, it's only restricted to GPU-accelerated properties (currently opacity, transform and -vendorPrefix-transform).

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/style_pages